# How to support two types of function arguments in python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I would like to design a function `f(x)` whose input could be

- one object
- or a list of objects

In the second case, `f(x)` should return a list of the corresponding results.

I am thinking of designing it as follow.

```
def f(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [f(y) for y in x]
    # some calculation
    # from x to result

    return result
```

Is this a good design? What would be the canonical way to do this?

Comment: It is a common pattern to convert a non-list argument to a one item list at the beginning of the function. Afterwards you don't need to care out the type of the argument anymore.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. Where can I learn the common design patterns? Is there a book on this?

Comment: Question for site resources or books are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not good design.

Design the function to take only one datatype. If the caller has only one item, it's trivial for them to wrap that in a list before calling.

```
result = f([list x])
```

Or, have the function only accept a single value and the caller can easily apply that function to a list:

```
result = map(f, [x,  y, z])
```

Comment: I'd say the opposite - design the function to do one thing and let the caller create a list when wanted. But I've done exactly what OP did in a framework where actions on multiple hosts were automatically aggregated by an abstraction layer. I don't think what OP does is definitively poor design in a highly malleable environment like python.

Answer (score 4):

They can easily map over the function when they have a list(example):

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1 #calcuation

lst = map(f, [1, 2, 3])
print(lst) # [2, 3, 4]
```

And remember: The function should do one thing and do it well :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid it. My biggest issue with it is that sometimes you're returning a list, and sometimes you're returning an object. I'd make it work on a list *or* an object, and then have the user deal with either wrapping the object, of calling the function in a list comprehension.
If you really do need to have it work on both I think you're better off using:

```
def func(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = [obj]
    # continue
```

That way you're always returning a list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the implementation may be valid (but with room for improvement). The problem is that you're creating an ambigous and unexpected behaviour. The best way would be to have 2 different functions `f(x)` and `f_on_list()` or something like this, where the second apply the first to a list.